# How to get delivery report from SMSC using SMPP and C#

Tags: c#, smpp

I'm using `SMPP` client with `C#` in Vs 2010 to send SMS to SMSC. I just can't figure out how to get the delivery report for the sent messages. I used `QuerySM` to get the status of the message, but it's returning OK Status even if I send an SMS to the number that is not in use.

**Here is my code for getting Delivery Report:**

```
QuerySm deliver = new QuerySm(_MessageID, SrcTon, SrcNpi, SrcAddr);
client.Query(deliver);
```

Comment: Could I ask which library you're using ?

Comment: @Oswin I'm using Inetlab.SMPP.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `QuerySmResp` to get the Delivery Report.

This is the code to check for the Delivery Status of the SMS Message:

```
QuerySmResp qresp = client.Query(_MessageID, SrcTon, SrcNpi, SrcAddr);
string _Delivery = qresp.MessageState.ToString();
```

`MessageState` property will show the status of the message and it's members are:

None

Enroute

Delivered

Expired

Deleted

Undeliverable

Accepted

Unknown

Rejected

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the SMSC you're using doesn't support `query_sm`, in this case they may have implemented a placeholder `query_sm_resp` PDU with a OK status for every request.

You could set the `registered_delivery` flag in `submit_sm` to 1 and listen for incoming `deliver_sm` PDUs, so you get the delivery reports from them, instead of querying them for every message you send.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't do C#, I just know SMPP.